# Can Node.js socket handle multiple write messages? Weird bug

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am writing a node.js server and i am experiencing a weird problem 
heres the code

```
   socket.write(">> first message \0","utf8",function(){ } );
   socket.write(">> second message \0","utf8",function(){ });
```

when i listen at the client side (ADOBE FLASH SOCKET) . it only recieves 1 message twice
and if i reverse the order of the code the message coming later only gets recieved twice , any clue on how to solve this ?

I am sure that this bug aint in programming because i have checked it like a hundred times, i also tried to make a stack explicitly then found out that node.js is supposed to mantain a stack internally ).

---

My node version is 0.5.1 running on windows 7 (the windows binary distributed on the website)

Comment: THe voted answer isnt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the second piece of data in the callback of the first:

```
socket.write(">> first message \0","utf8",function(){
    socket.write(">> second message \0","utf8",function(){ });
} );
```

Comment: What if i am having more then 1 sockets I tried that. this.Write was the best solution i thought as ... u know it will make sure only this socket writes the response but it fauled

Comment: check your flash code, i can't imagine such a hard bug in node.js

Comment: mhm okay i think its related to flash aswell and NOT nodejs

Comment: ah the api i am using uses a global variable(probably) which makes it crash... meh